# get_user can't read variable

Tags: meta-query, user-meta

I have this little routine to find the user_id based on a usermeta field..

```
$scaleData = json_decode($reading, TRUE);
$deviceid = $scaleData["imei"];
echo $deviceid; // check to confirm is working. Yup

$WhoIsUser = get_users(
  array(
   'meta_key' => 'deviceid',
   'meta_value' => '$deviceid'
 )
);

$CurrentUser = $WhoIsUser[0]->ID;
echo $CurrentUser; //returns nothing
```

But if I switch 'meta_value' => 45455 (iow a known device number) it returns the ID no problem. I've tried both $deviceid and '$deviceid'
What am I missing?

Comment: I think you should remore the quotes around $deviceid, that should be the reason why it is not getting a value. With the quotes he is not loading the value of the variable, but just the string. But you said you already tried that... have you tried outputting the value to see if the Id is correctly saved in the variable you use as meta_value?

Comment: Got it! I needed to use "double-quotes". Such a simple mistake and hours lost! Thx your comment got me thinking on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs double quotes

```
$WhoIsUser = get_users(
  array(
   'meta_key' => 'deviceid',
   'meta_value' => "$deviceid"
 )
);
```

Comment: Ideally it wouldn't have quotes at all. You'd only use double quotes if you were using the variable as part of a longer string.

Comment: True. And it works without "" . Now. So there must have been another mistake in there too that I was making...